# Android NFC: Is there a callback when a tag is in range?

Tags: android, nfc

Is there a callback from the Android NFC stack to a foreground application when an NFC device is in range?

Filtering Logcat for "NFC" shows the following useful stack messages:

**Tag In Range**

```
2019-07-01 16:39:44.013 3712-3712/? D/NativeNfcTag: Connect to a tech with a different handle
2019-07-01 16:39:44.175 3712-6736/? D/NativeNfcTag: Starting background presence check
```

**Tag Out Of Range**

```
2019-07-01 16:42:15.808 3712-6788/? D/NativeNfcTag: Tag lost, restarting 
2019-07-01 16:42:15.811 3712-6788/? D/NativeNfcTag: Stopping background presence check
```

I would like to use these events to update a user interface indicating that an NFC device is in range *before* the stack sends the intent.

Answer (score 0):

`NfcA.isConnected()` will test if you are connected and return a boolean.
you can call it permanently from another thread.